# Browser default values

Tags: html, css, browser, fonts, cross-browser

I am developing a simple page with a form.
When I put a input text in the page, the characters that appear inside the input element have the browser default values, in chrome using the developers tools I can see that the font defaults to "webkit-small-control". But one of the fields that will appear in the page will be just a span field with data like this

```
<td>
   <span id="readOnlyField">data</span>
</td>
```

When I render the page the data inside the span field is not equal to the data inside the input text field. My question is, how can I know the fonts and colors that the browser is applying to the input text field ? I can not use the value "webkit-small-control" because will not work in another browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you can't know those values, because the defaults vary across browsers. Also, a user can set things like the default font family and style and hyperlink colors.

It is a good practice to use a "CSS reset" stylesheet to override browser defaults with your own "base" styles. There are lots of CSS reset examples on the web, for example [the HTML5 Doctor's one](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/) or [Eric Meyer's one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). While your question is only about font style, resetting also other styles prevents many headaches in the long run.

Answer (score 5):

I have only noticed this in Safari on a Mac. In order to make everything display the content as expected you need to override Safaris user agent stylesheet:

```
font: -webkit-small-control;
```

can be overridden using this in your reset.css:

```
button, input, textarea, select, isindex, datagrid {
    font: inherit;
}
```

I cannot seem to find this in any reset.css but it done the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no way to know for sure what default font-size the browser will choose.**

You should instead reset the CSS (with [Normalize](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) for example) and further style your pages, for example:

```
span.some-class {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #333;
}
```

And then your HTML:

```
<span class="some-class" id="readOnlyField">data</span>
```

Comment: Yeah, both your and my answers are solid. This is bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

that is the reason you should reset all the styles at first or use some established css framework like [blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) and avoid reinventing the wheel.

You should probably be overriding any style that you want in your css to aovid browser defaults

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but there may be people around here who think that users should be in control of their own font sizes and that suggesting that all webpages use their owner's preferences instead of honouring the users' should be downvoted.

Comment: You might be right, but that doesn't justify a downvote. The question was how to do this and whether this is possible, not if it is "right". Besides, it **is** possible to define custom font sizes and still respect user's settings - using something like `body { font-size: 100%; }` sets body font size to the user's preferred font size (which is the default anyway) and you can then derive other font sizes by using % as the unit in the rest of CSS.

Comment: True. And besides, if users want to always use their own fonts instead of the website's, the browsers have settings for that.

Answer (score 0):

The default color for all major browsers for fonts is #000 but you can set it to whatever you want. The font you can set to whatever you want as long as it's on the system viewing it. Those defaults can be found by Googling.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no known way you could find out, on your page, which font the browser uses by default. Neither can you specify in CSS that the browser render a `span` element using whatever font it uses by default for an `input` element.

But you can make text in `span` and `input` elements look the same (with the usual CSS Caveats, of course) by explicitly setting their `font-family` and `font-size`, e.g.

```
input, span { font: 100% Arial, sans-serif; }
```

In theory, you might need to set other properties too (there is no law against a browser displaying `input` element contents in blinking purple underlined by default), but this should take care of things in practice. Note that font size setting is needed, because browsers generally use reduced font size (about 90%) for input boxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use javascript, you can use `getComputedStyle` to find this data (check out [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle)).

For old IE browsers, you would need to use the `currentStyle` property (check out [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html)).

To copy ALL styles from one element to another, you could do something like this (I have simplified this to support modern browsers only):

```
var spanElement = document.querySelector('#mySpanElement');
var inputElement = document.querySelector('#myInputElement');
var styles = getComputedStyle(inputElement);
for (var name in styles) {
    spanElement.style[name] = styles[name];
}
```

You will probably find you want to filter them, or only take a few ones you really want.

Answer (score 0):

It is a behavior of WebKit.

See https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50092

For a solution see: http://sijobling.com/tips/css-fix-for-html5-search-in-webkit/